# iCloud setting like clear app in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, core-data, icloud

I have tried many iCloud example but I want to migrate iCloud to local and local to iCloud without duplication like in Clear app in ios. I have tried this example too
[iCloudStoreManager](https://github.com/alekseyn/iCloudStoreManager)

Can You please help me to solve it.

Comment: Avoiding duplicates can sometimes be tricky. I wrote up a blog post about it a while ago that gets into details and possible fixes: http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/icloud-complications-part-2

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. If the user wants to keep the cloud data, delete the local store *before* creating the persistent store with iCloud settings turned on. iCloud should then populate your local store with the data from the cloud automatically.
2. If the user wants to keep the local data, migrate the existing local store to a new temporary store with no iCloud settings, then use the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` method
   `+removeUbiquitousContentAndPersistentStoreAtURL:error:` to remove the existing iCloud data. Finally, migrate the temporary store back with iCloud settings turned on. You should end up with only the data from the temporary store.

Another option is to not remove any data at all, but deduplicate data as mentioned by Tom Harrington.

Lastly, you might have more luck with the [Ensembles](http://ensembles.io) open source framework. It works with iCloud, but — being an open source project — is more transparent than Apple's solution, and generally easier to get up and running. (Disclosure: I am a developer of Ensembles)